# How to set background color of current item in scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontal `recyclerview` which can show 1.5 items at a time, means 1 complete item on screen, and partial view of second item.

I want to change the background color or set alpha of the main item or the item at the current position.

If i use following code it sets alpha for second item.

```
  if(position == 1){
            holder.itemView.setAlpha(0.5f);
        }else{
            holder.itemView.setAlpha(1.0f);
        }
```

but i want to know a dynamic way to set alpha `0.5f` for rest of the items, and `1.0f` for the current index.

Comment: How do you know , which is your current index , when list is scrolling

Comment: @Tufan : I have added a breakpoint `onBindViewHolder` and whenever i scroll it jumps to that breakpoint and gives the current index.

Answer (score 1):

Any visible child depends on the LayoutManager. If you are using LinearLayoutManager or GridLayoutManager, you can use these functions

```
int findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
int findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
int findLastVisibleItemPosition();
int findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

For example:

> GridLayoutManager layoutManager = ((GridLayoutManager)mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager());
>       int firstVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

you can use these functions..